# Print out List using const &

Tags: c++, list, reference, constants

Hey I have a list that has values in it, I want to print it out using const &. I can do it with by just referencing it but when I put const in I get an error. I'm not sure why this is the case because the code won't edit the list. This is my code.

```
// Prints out the list declared
template<typename DATA_TYPE>
    void print(const list<DATA_TYPE> &myList){
    for(list<DATA_TYPE>::iterator pos = myList.begin(); pos != myList.end(); pos++){
        DATA_TYPE currentWord = *pos;
        cout << currentWord << " ";
    }
}
```

If you could also go through the logic behind the error that'd be cool, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your `list` is declared as `const`, you need to use a `const_iterator`:

```
list<DATA_TYPE>::const_iterator pos
```

p.s. For future reference, please copy and paste any compiler errors that you get into your question.

Comment: If I do that then I get garbage values out. And I assume this is because the iterator can't increment. If that's the case then could you even print out a list using const&?

Comment: @wzsun if you're getting garbage out you have another bug that isn't related to how the iterator is working.

Comment: My bad, yea I just forgot to change the data type to the correct one thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `const_iterator`, not iterator.